# Accessing field in decoded json string PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to access the field 'id' of the first song in this decoded json string using php. I've tried all possible combinations like this one:

$response->songs[0]->id

This is my decoded json string:

```
   Array (
[response] => Array (
[status] => Array (
[version] => 4.2
[code] => 0
[message] => Success
)
[songs] => Array (
[0] => Array (
[artist_id] => ARRH63Y1187FB47783
[id] => SOKGWES13D647BE466
[artist_name] => Kanye West
[title] => All Of The Lights
)
[1] => Array (
[artist_id] => ARRH63Y1187FB47783
[id] => SOHBKVU14509A9F6C3
[artist_name] => Kanye West
[title] => All Of The Lights
)
[2] => Array (
[artist_id] => ARRH63Y1187FB47783
[id] => SODELAY13AD1ACC8CF
[artist_name] => Kanye West
[title] => All Of The Lights
)
[3] => Array (
[artist_id] => ARRH63Y1187FB47783
[id] => SOUDIYM14B7C7B2D95
[artist_name] => Kanye West
[title] => All of the Lights
)
[4] => Array (
[artist_id] => ARRH63Y1187FB47783
[id] => SOTEMPJ13DB921F71F
[artist_name] => Kanye West
[title] => All of the Lights (
Remix
)
)
[5] => Array (
[artist_id] => ARRH63Y1187FB47783
[id] => SOXIDRL13CCFBBC829
[artist_name] => Kanye West
[title] => All Of The Lights
[LbLuke Rmx]
)
[6] => Array (
[artist_id] => ARRH63Y1187FB47783
[id] => SOTJZSO12D857905F6
[artist_name] => Kanye West
[title] => All Of The Lights (
Interlude
)
)
[7] => Array (
[artist_id] => ARVCDGF12FE08689BA
[id] => SOGLUJD130516E0D00
[artist_name] => Made famous by Kanye West
[title] => All of the lights
)
)
)
)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the value of the second parameter of `json_decode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$id = $json_array['response']['songs'][0]['id'];
```

Explanation

Take a look at the response, your response is a multidimensional array, This means that you have an array formed by several arrays, and each one can contain one or more arrays.

In the first array you have is "response", this one contains the rest of them, so..

```
$id = $json_array['response']
```

from this array you have to go nesting inside until you get your wanted element. Which is contained into another array songs, so..

```
$id = $json_array['response']['songs']
```

This one has several elements indexed by numbers, as you want the id from the first song we pick the 0 element,

```
$id = $json_array['response']['songs'][0]
```

after this you can get the element you want:

```
$id = $json_array['response']['songs'][0]['id'];
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!
I'll accept your answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

The json_decode return array, so to access you do like this:

```
$id = $json_array['response']['songs'][0]['id'];
```

If you want to work in Object way you need to convert:

```
$object = (object) $json_array;
$object->response->songs[0]->id
```